Trying to run react within rust
I am trying to run a react app via a rust function, for context main_command and args are variables taken from a .toml file but they together represent: "sudo npm start". The perm path was because the error I got was that permission was denied in that folder so I put it there to give permissions on that folder. Somehow I still get some errors, maybe I can't even do this within a script. How can I fix it?
The react app is transmitted via TCP.
pub fn run_wrangler(config: ProjectConfig) {
    let mut chmod_command = Command::new("chmod");
    let perm_path = format!("{}/{}", config.path.clone(), "node_modules/.bin/react-scripts");
    chmod_command.arg("+x").arg(PathBuf::from(perm_path));

    match chmod_command.status() {
        Ok(status) if status.success() => {
            println!("Successfully set execute permissions for react-scripts.");
        },
        Ok(status) => {
            eprintln!("Failed to set execute permissions, exit status: {}", status);
            return;
        },
        Err(e) => {
            eprintln!("Failed to run chmod: {}", e);
            return;
        }
    }


    let (main_command, args) = fragment_command(config.wrangler_config.build.command);
    println!("Project dir: {}", config.path);

    let mut command = Command::new("sh");
    command.arg("-c");
    command.arg(format!("{} {}", main_command, args.join(" ")));
    command.current_dir(PathBuf::from(config.path));  // Set the working directory

    match command.output() {
        Ok(output) => {
            let stdout = String::from_utf8_lossy(&output.stdout);
            let stderr = String::from_utf8_lossy(&output.stderr);

            println!("Stdout: {}", stdout);
            println!("Stderr: {}", stderr);
        },
        Err(e) => {
            eprintln!("Error: {}", e);
            return;
        }
    }
}

I get this when I try to run it:
Stdout:
> my-app@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

Stderr:
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1215
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '../scripts/start'
Require stack:
- /Users/---/Desktop/Coding/cloudflare/worker/my-app/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1212:15)
    at Function.resolve (node:internal/modules/helpers:133:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/---/Desktop/Coding/cloudflare/worker/my-app/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts:31:23)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1460:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1544:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1275:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:12)
    at wrapModuleLoad (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:212:19)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:158:5)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:30:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/---/Desktop/Coding/cloudflare/worker/my-app/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts'
  ]
}

Node.js v22.3.0

Have you tried running that command on the command-line, outside of Rust? If it works, this is not a Rust/programming question, it's an issue you need to figure out with the script. If it doesn't work, then we still have something to look into

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
